# Find an overload address by its parameters only

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

Assuming that a function (which can be either a global function or a member function) is overloaded only on its parameters (so that its overloads will always be all const or all non-const). Is there a way to write a template that would select an overload address according to the specified parameter? For example:

```
struct Foo {
    double bar(double n, double m);
    int bar(int n, int m);
};

auto addressDouble = find_overload<&Foo::bar, double, double>::address;
auto addressInt = find_overload<&Foo::bar, int, int>::address;
```

An interesting answer I've found is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25875538/880703), but unfortunately it only deal with forwarding a call to the right overload, and not actually fetching the overload address so that it can be used later.

Last note: a perfect solution should work on a released Clang version. Apart from this requirement, any available C++1z feature and lower can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you can access to address of an overloaded function you have to specify which version do you need to.

```
template<typename ...TA>
struct find_overload
{
    template<typename TObj, typename TR>
    using member_func_t = TR(TObj::*)(TA...);

    template< typename TObj, typename TR >
    static constexpr auto get_address(member_func_t<TObj, TR> func) -> member_func_t<TObj, TR>
    {
        return func;
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr auto address = find_overload<double, double>::get_address(&Foo::bar);
}
```

Comment: _which can be either a global function or a member function_. The answer doesn't address the requirement for free functions.

Comment: @skypjack Yes it doesnt address free functions but the main purpuse here is to provide the basic idea that how it can be implemented. OP himself can change and extend provided solutions to match his requirment

Comment: I don't see any reason for down voting. It is better to provide an explation for down votes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `static_cast<>()` :

```
auto addressDouble = static_cast<double(*)(double, double)>(&Foo:bar);
auto addressInt = static_cast<int(*)(int, int)>(&Foo:bar);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, using `static_cast` still requires to specify the function return type, which is what I was trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

Despite the [working answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41661700/4987285) of @MRB, a more compact solution exists.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include<iostream>

struct Foo {
    double bar(double n, double m) {}
    int bar(int n, int m) {}
};

double quux(double n, double m) {}
int quux(int n, int m) {}

template<typename... A, typename T, typename R>
constexpr auto find_overload(R(T::*f)(A...)) { return f; }

template<typename... A, typename R>
constexpr auto find_overload(R(*f)(A...)) { return f; }

int main() {
    auto fooAddressDouble = find_overload<double, double>(&Foo::bar);
    auto fooAddressInt = find_overload<int, int>(&Foo::bar);
    Foo foo;
    (foo.*fooAddressDouble)(0., 0.);
    (foo.*fooAddressInt)(0, 0);

    auto globalAddressDouble = find_overload<double, double>(&quux);
    auto globalAddressInt = find_overload<int, int>(&quux);
    globalAddressDouble(0., 0.);
    globalAddressInt(0, 0);
}
```

As you can see, `find_overload` accepts both free functions and member functions (for which it deduces the class type as well as the return type).

Comment: Despite free functions, `const` overload of member or free functions also need to be considered.

Comment: @MRB OP said something different in the question actually.