# What's the correct syntax for passing an explicitly specified function template overload as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, overload-resolution

Consider the following two function templates

```
template<class T> void g(std::vector<T>&) {}
template<class T> void g(std::list<T>&) {}
```

together with the intermediate function

```
template<class Fct, class Container> void h(Fct&& f, Container& c)
{
   f(c);
}
```

How do I call `h` with an explicit instantiation of `g` (like the first solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25871520/9593596))? I tried these

```
std::vector<int> vec;

h(g<void(std::vector<int>&)>, vec); // Error, can't deduce template paramter Fct
h(g<void<int>(std::vector<int>&)>, vec); // Same problem
```

but now I'm lacking imagination for trying out an alternative syntax (I know that I can wrap the call in a lambda or a function object, but that's not what I want to do here). Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: cppreference adresses a similar probleme [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address)

Comment: Do you intend `g` to take rvalue reference or forwarding reference?

Comment: Does it matter if the argument type is a universal reference?

Comment: @lubgr `g` does not use forwarding references, it uses rvalue-references. Forwarding references only apply directly to `T`, not to `std::vector<T>` or `std::list<T>`.

Comment: Right, thanks! I'll adjust the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself:

```
h<void(std::vector<int>&)>(g, vec);
```

It was confused about which function template to explicitly instantiate and incorrectly chose `g` instead of `h`.