# Postponing function execution using function pointers

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I want to create a variable from a Command class that will receive a function and its arguments and execute it when Execute is called, but I don't know how to pass the constructors arguments to the class member variables since I can't tell how the function pointer is going to be.

Here is some pseudo-code for what I have in mind.

```
class Command {
public:
  template<_Fn, _Args...>
  Command(_Fn&& _function, _Args&&... _args)
  {
  }

  void Execute(){
  }
};

void Print(int _int, float _float){
  ...
}

void Print(const char* _text, unsigned int _uint){
  ...
}

int main(){
  Command cmd0 = Command(&Print, 5, 6.2f);
  Command cmd1 = Command(&Print, "Hello", 2u);
  cmd1.Execute();
  cmd0.Execute();
}
```

Comment: Looks like a primer in `std::function`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to reinvent this just use `std::function` and `std::bind`:

```
int main(){
  std::function<void()> cmd0 = std::bind(&PrintIntFloat, 5, 6.2f);
  std::function<void()> cmd1 = std::bind(&PrintStringInt, "Hello", 2u);
  cmd1();
  cmd0();
}
```

Note that I renamed the functions because [lifting overload sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871381/c-overloaded-function-as-template-argument) is problematic in C++.

Or you can use lambdas in which case no lifting needed (thank you deW1 for the suggestion):

```
std::function<void()> cmd0 = [] { Print(5, 6.2f); };
std::function<void()> cmd1 = [] { Print("Hello", 2u); };
```

Comment: Why pay for bind when you can use lambdas?

Comment: @deW1 is there any practical difference between them compared to the overhead of `std::function`?

Comment: But also avoiding `std::function` in lambda case: maybe simply `auto cmd0 = [] { Print(5, 6.2f); };`

Comment: @max66, it's hard too tell for sure from the question, but it is likely that OP would want to use these `Command`s interchangeably since he used the same type for them.

Comment: @eerorika I'd say the overhead of std::function doesn't really change but you still pay extra for bind, https://godbolt.org/z/2kVfS_

Comment: It worked. My main plan was to create an unordered_map<std::string, Command> and create a ExecuteCommand(const char* _cmd) to execute a command from the map.

Comment: @BrianBatista for your next question, it's always good to include your desired outcome or your desired use case.