# Passing overloaded function and args to template function

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I'd like to send the two overloaded `fun()`s to one template that handles them plus their arguments. This is my attempt so far:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Demo
{};

template<typename Function, typename... Args>
void call(Function func(Args...), Args &&...args)
{
    func(forward<Args>(args)...);       // execute function with args
}

void fun(int first, int second, int third)
{
    cout << "fun with ints\n";
}

void fun(Demo &&dem1, Demo &&dem2)      // adding overload causes the ambiguity
{
    cout << "fun with Demos\n";
}

int main()
{
    call(fun, 1, 2, 3);  
                   
    call(fun, Demo{}, Demo{});     
}
```

The compiler complains that it can't find a matching function for the calls in main():

```
main.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cc:27:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘call(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int, int, int)’
   27 |     call(fun, 1, 2, 3);
      |                      ^
main.cc:10:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class Function, class ... Args> void call(Function (*)(Args ...), Args&& ...)’
   10 | void call(Function func(Args...), Args &&...args)
      |      ^~~~
main.cc:10:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cc:27:22: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Function’
   27 |     call(fun, 1, 2, 3);
      |                      ^
main.cc:29:29: error: no matching function for call to ‘call(<unresolved overloaded function type>, Demo, Demo)’
   29 |     call(fun, Demo{}, Demo{});
      |                             ^
main.cc:10:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class Function, class ... Args> void call(Function (*)(Args ...), Args&& ...)’
   10 | void call(Function func(Args...), Args &&...args)
      |      ^~~~
main.cc:10:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cc:29:29: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘Function’
   29 |     call(fun, Demo{}, Demo{});
      |
```

Any ideas to find a solution to this puzzle would be highly appreciated!
(the solution at [C++ overloaded function as template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871381/c-overloaded-function-as-template-argument) did not solve my problem because I cannot change the way that call() is called in main() )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for compilation error is that the compiler does not know which `fun` overload you are actually going to use.

To resolve this error, you just need to cast your function parameter to the right overload like:

```cpp
int main()
{
    call( static_cast< void(*)(int, int, int) >( fun ), 1, 2, 3 );  

    call( static_cast< void(*)(Demo&&, Demo&&) >( fun ), Demo{}, Demo{} );

    return 0;
}
```

**FYI**, what your `call` function is trying to do is actually defined by the standard. It is [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) function and it comes with C++17 standard.

Comment: I ended up solving it like this:
call<void (*)(int, int)>(fun, 1, 3);
call<void (*)(Demo&&, Demo&&)>(fun, Demo{}, Demo{}); 
Thanks anyways for your response!