# What's the least verbose way to hint a overloaded function template as template parameter

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction, function-templates

I'm trying to create a function template which accepts `std::max` and others with compatible prototypes:

```
template <typename F>
int f(F g)
{
    return g(1,2);
}
```

Because of the many overloads, the template argument F cannot be inferred f.e. for `std::max`, so this will fail:

```
f(std::max);
```

One possibility is to hint with a `static_cast`:

```
f(static_cast<int const& (*)(int const&,int const&)>(std::max));
```

I'm looking for a less verbose way while still being able to also easily pass any other sort of matching function, like f.e.

```
f([](int i, int j) { return 3; });
f(std::function<int(int,int)>([](int i, int j) { return 4; }));
```

[Here's a godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1W45Tz).

If there's an easy way for C++11 and C++14 this would be great but if there's only one for C++17 and above this would also help a lot.

Comment: Just pass the lambda as is? As in `f([](int a, int b) { return std::max(a, b); })`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25875538/817643 if you find yourself doing this a lot. Note that it doesn't address `noexcept`-ness. Which would require some more repetition in the macro.

Comment: sorry for the nitpick, but expressiveness is something desirable. I suppose you rather mean verbose, long-winded, clunky

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 no need to be sorry; you're totally right. I edited that.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `std::max` not your function.

There is no way you could modify your function to make it accept a set of overloads. A set of overloads is just not something you can pass along. What you can pass along is an object with overloaded `operator()`. For example

```
struct foo {
    template <typename T> bool operator()(T a,T b){return a+b;}
};

f(foo{}); // OK
```

`std::max` however is a function template and you need to instantiate the function before the function can be passed to `f`. Nothing you can do about that. Though you not necessarily need `std::function` or `static_cast` to pick the right overload. As mentioned in a comment you can do

```
 f([](int a, int b) { return std::max(a, b); });
```

This triggers instantiation of `std::max<int>` inside the lambda, or if you prefer to select the type inside `f` you can do similar as in the above example:

```
 f([](auto a, auto b) { return std::max(a,b); });
```

This lambda expression is similar to the above `foo`. You have a concrete object and only the `operator()` is a template which only gets instantiated when called, such that in `f` you could even do:

```
template <typename F>
int f(F g)
{
    if (some_condition) return g(1,2); // calls std::max<int>
    else return g(1.2,1.4);            // calls std::max<double>
                                       // (though int is returned anyhow)
}

f([](auto a, auto b) { return std::max(a,b); });
```

Comment: I don't like to admit it but i really don't like the overhead introduced by the lambda for unoptimized builds; see https://godbolt.org/z/81YcvW

Comment: @jesses well I like it that it can be optimized away completely in a non-debug built https://godbolt.org/z/fG811x. Why do you care about overhead in a debug build?

Comment: I measure roughly a factor of 2; when called billions of times this can get significant with the codebase i'm working with.

Comment: @jesse ok, but why do you care about performance of a non optimized build?

Comment: When hunting down regressions it often takes up to an hour until the unoptimized build reaches the code point where things start to diverge and release builds often optimize away too much to show enough useful information. There is still the disassebly for such cases but i try to avoid it if i can.

Comment: @jesses ok, in this circumstances, I'd go for the static cast ;)